# Why does the composition operation for formal power series need to have conditions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, power-series

(Formal power series composition) For some functions, a reasonable composition can be computed $(f \circ  g) (x) = f(g(x))$, and this holds for most other objects as well.

The algebraic structure of polynomials also allows for a reasonable composition, denoted as $P \circ  Q = P(Q)$. Expanding upon this structure, we arrive at formal power series. However, before defining a unified composition operation for these, there are certain clear-cut definitions for power series that should be adhered to. Following this, a newly defined algorithm is permitted. Specifically, if $A$ and $B$ are two formal power series, the operation $A \circ  B$ is defined when: Either $A$ is a polynomial or $B$ has $b_0 = 0$ (with $B = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$).

My question is, if not enforced, is it advantageous to adopt the definition "borrowed" from polynomials? Is it consistent or does it pose challenges? What is the purpose of these conditions? I'm somewhat skeptical and seeking clarity.
Thank you.

Comment: Try composing 1 + x + x^2 + … with itself and you will quickly see where the problem lies. In short, the fact that you cannot add an infinite number of 1’s is the problem - divergent sums.

Comment: @hellHound This is a sequence of formal power series. It has an algebraic structure, not an analytic one. Convergence or divergence is not considered here. Therefore, it is not the issue. Thank you.

Comment: You misunderstood @hellHound's comment. What diverges is not the power series you get but the first (and in fact every) coefficient. So you simply don't get a power series. As (s)he said, "Try composing $\dots$ and you will quickly see $\dots$."

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
\begin{align}
F(x)&=1+x+x^2+\dots\\
G(x)&=1
\end{align}
$$
There is no sensible way to define the composition $(F\circ G)(x)$.
$$
\begin{align}
(F\circ G)(x)
&=1+G(x)+G(x)^2+\dots
\\&=1+1^1+1^2+\dots
\\&\stackrel{???}=\infty
\end{align}
$$
This is why we require $F$ to be a polynomial, or $G(0)=0$, for the composition $(F\circ G)(x)$ to be a well-defined formal power series.

Answer (score 2):

The concrete argument, as other have said, is that if you write down what happens when you try to define $A \circ B$ when $B(0) \neq 0$ you run into an infinite sum (namely the infinite sum $A(B(0))$). The two conditions that either $A$ is a polynomial or $B(0) = 0$ are conditions that guarantee that all the sums defining the coefficients are actually finite.

Here is a more abstract discussion. Polynomial composition can be described in terms of endomorphisms $F : k[x] \to k[x]$ of the $k$-algebra of polynomials. By the universal property, such an endomorphism is freely determined by where it sends $x$, which can be arbitrary, so write $F(x) = f(x) \in k[x]$ (note that somewhat confusingly the $(x)$ notation means two different things on the left and right side of this expression). Then for a general polynomial $g(x) \in k[x]$ we have

$$F(g(x)) = g(f(x))$$

so $F$ is the endomorphism which sends a polynomial $g$ to the precomposite $g \circ f$. Moreover $f$ can be arbitrary.

The analogous discussion for formal power series is to consider endomorphisms $F : k[[x]] \to k[[x]]$ of the $k$-algebra of formal power series which, furthermore, are continuous with respect to the $x$-adic topology (this turns out to make the answer nice and also I have no idea what the discontinuous endomorphisms look like, if there even are any). Because polynomials $k[x]$ are dense in $k[[x]]$ in the $x$-adic topology, it is again true that such an endomorphism is determined by where it sends $x$, so again write $F(x) = f(x) \in k[[x]]$, which is now a formal power series.

But $f$ can't be arbitrary here, because the ideal $(x) \in k[[x]]$ is the *unique* maximal ideal of $k[[x]]$, meaning it must be preserved by all ring endomorphisms. So we must have $f(x) \in (x)$, meaning that $f(0) = 0$.

However, this turns out to be the only constraint, and if $f(0) = 0$ then for any other power series $g(x) \in k[x]$ we again have

$$F(g(x)) = g(f(x))$$

(sketch: this is true for polynomials $g$ because $F$ is a homomorphism, and then $x$-adic continuity shows that it's true for arbitrary $g$, again because polynomials are dense).

Comment: You can also recover the version where $g$ is a polynomial and $f$ is arbitrary this way but you need to do it a bit differently. Instead we need to consider endomorphisms of the forgetful functor from $k$-algebras to sets.